# Is it possible to know which of connected LCD monitors are turned on?

Tags: shell-script, x11

I would like to enable output automatically only, if the connected monitor is turned on (but it could be in a power management state).

Comment: `enable output automatically` - do you mean use `xrandr --output <OUTPUT> --auto`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, for example, but only for the monitors that are switched on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ddcutil](https://www.ddcutil.com) to check if the given
monitor is turned on by checking if value of VCP 0xd6 code is set to
anything else than 0x05 as specified in table 8-5 of the [VESA Monitor
Control Command
Set](http://read.pudn.com/downloads515/doc/2139715/mccsV3.pdf):

```
$ sudo ddcutil -d 1 getvcp d6 --terse |& awk '{ print $NF }'
x01
```

That means that the first display is turned on.

```
$ sudo ddcutil -d 1 getvcp d6 --terse |& awk '{ print $NF }'
x05
```

That means that the first display is turned off.

The hardest part is to match output specified by xrandr with a display
identity that could be used with ddcutil. One of the ways I could
think if is to extract EDID from xrandr output, parse it with
edid-decode, get a serial number and use it with ddcutil (even though
ddcutil accepts --edid parameter I wasn't able to use for some
reason). Altogether, the entire `xrandr-turned-on.sh` script could
look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]
then
    printf "Check if monitor represented by xrandr output is turned on.\n
Usage: %s output\n" "$0"
    exit 1
fi

for prog in ddcutil edid-decode
do
    if ! command -v "$prog" >/dev/null
    then
        printf "%s not found. Exiting.\n" "$prog" >&2
    exit 1
fi
done

set -e

serial="$(xrandr --prop | awk -v output="$1" '$1 ~ output {getline; for (i=1; i<=16; i++) {getline; printf("%s", $1)}}' | edid-decode | grep "Serial number" | cut -d: -f2 | sed "s,^ ,,")"

state="$(sudo ddcutil -n "$serial" getvcp d6 --terse | awk '{print $NF}')"
if [ "$state" != "x05" ]
then
    printf "Monitor for output %s turned on\n" "$1"
else
    printf "Monitor for output %s turned off\n" "$1"
fi
```

(Notice that usage of `getline` is rather [discouraged in awk scripts](http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline))

Usage:

```
$ ./xrandr-turned-on.sh HDMI3
Monitor for output HDMI3 turned on
```

Comment: Unfortunately my monitors do not give their serial number that way in EDID. Besides `sudo ddcutil detect` tells my second display is "Invalid display" that fails in DDC communication, and it does not show serial number for either display. For my first monitor the code is 0x01 no matter whether the monitor is on or off.

Comment: @jarno: what monitors do you have and how are they connected to your computer - HDMI, DVI, USB?

Comment: One is Samsung FullHD monitor from year 2012, connected via HDMI. The other is Philips HDTV from year 2013, connected via HDMI, too. In the computer side I have DP to HDMI adapters for both.

Comment: Hmm, DDC is not always implemented correctly by the manufacturers. Serial number in EDID is optional. I can for sure say that the suggested ddcutil method works with my Dell monitors.  There are many reports of ddcutil not working with some monitors or working in unstable manner. Sorry but I cannot help you further with this.

Comment: `Serial number in EDID is optional` - it's not the largest problem here as I've just learned how to use EDID reported by `xrandr --props` with ddcutil but since ddcutil reports incorrect status it doesn't make any sense to use it.

Comment: BTW, do you use TVs or computer monitors? I have no idea if VCP feature of DDC is supported by TVs.

Comment: For my monitors there is some serial number as a last word of "Manufacturer:" line, but it does not work with `ddcutil`.

Comment: The first one is TV. (I mentioned HDTV above.) The other one is plain LCD monitor. "DDC communication failed" comes with the TV, besides it does not support display power management but shows "no signal" text soon after controlled by `xset dpms force off`. It has its own timer for turn off if I do not use the remote or TV's controls in given time, but I have disabled it, because it does not detect, if I use the device by computer.

Comment: You have to cut off the possible extension block by e.g. `head` before you pass the EDID string as an argument for `--edid` option of `ddcutil`: `sudo ddcutil --edid $(xrandr --prop | awk -v output="$1" '$1 ~ output {getline; for (i=1; i<=16; i++) {getline; printf("%s", $1)}}' | head -c 256) getvcp d6`. BTW I noticed that sometimes I have to run `ddcutil` few times to get the code.